# missing dependency for Faraday::Adapter::NetHttpPersistent: cannot load such file -- net/http/persistent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure-blob-storage

The latest version of `azure-storage-common 2.0.2` with persistent HTTP calls is failing with the following error:

```
missing dependency for Faraday::Adapter::NetHttpPersistent: cannot load such file -- net/http/persistent
```

The call is to `create_block_blob`.

The appropriate dependencies have been specified:

```rb
gem 'faraday_middleware', '1.0.0', {require: false}
gem 'net-http-persistent', '4.0.0', {require: false}
gem 'azure-storage-common', '2.0.2', {require: false}
gem 'azure-storage-blob', '2.0.1', {require: false}

require 'azure/storage/blob'
```

And yes, I can see `net-http-persistent` being bundled.

I tried putting: `require 'net/http/persistent'` here but it doesn't help.  The same error.

Any pointers?

EDIT:

Sorry I didn't make it clear.  I am using Bundler.  And `net-http-persistent` has been bundled.

I put `require 'net/http/persistent'` in front of every function call, and it still comes back with this error, even when the `require` statement returns `true` meaning that the module is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I first install the azure blob storage package by this:

```
gem install azure-storage-blob
```

Then, I use below code and it seems work fine:

```
require "openssl"
require "securerandom"
require "rbconfig"

# Require the azure storage blob rubygem
require "azure/storage/blob"

$stdout.sync = true

# This sample application creates a container in an Azure Blob Storage account,
# uploads data to the container, lists the blobs in the container, and downloads a blob to a local file.
def run_sample
    is_windows = (RbConfig::CONFIG["host_os"] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/)

    # Create a BlobService object
    blob_client = Azure::Storage::Blob::BlobService 

    begin

        # Create a BlobService object
        account_name = "yourstorageaccountname"
        account_key = "xxxxxx=="

            blob_client = Azure::Storage::Blob::BlobService.create(
            storage_account_name: account_name,
            storage_access_key: account_key
        )

        # Create a container
        container_name = "quickstartblobs" + SecureRandom.uuid
        puts "\nCreating a container: " + container_name
        container = blob_client.create_container(container_name)
        
        # Set the permission so the blobs are public
        blob_client.set_container_acl(container_name, "container")

        # Create a new block blob containing 'Hello, World!'
        blob_name = "QuickStart_" + SecureRandom.uuid + ".txt"
        blob_data = "Hello, World!"
        puts "\nCreating blob: " + blob_name
        blob_client.create_block_blob(container.name, blob_name, blob_data)

        # List the blobs in the container
        puts "\nList blobs in the container following continuation token"
        nextMarker = nil
        loop do
            blobs = blob_client.list_blobs(container_name, { marker: nextMarker })
            blobs.each do |blob|
                puts "\tBlob name: #{blob.name}"
            end
            nextMarker = blobs.continuation_token
            break unless nextMarker && !nextMarker.empty?
        end

        # Download the blob

        # Set the path to the local folder for downloading
        if(is_windows)
            local_path = File.expand_path("~/Documents")
        else 
            local_path = File.expand_path("~/")
        end

        # Create the full path to the downloaded file
        full_path_to_file = File.join(local_path, blob_name)

        puts "\nDownloading blob to " + full_path_to_file
        blob, content = blob_client.get_blob(container_name, blob_name)
        File.open(full_path_to_file,"wb") {|f| f.write(content)}

        puts "\nPaused, press the Enter key to delete resources created by the sample and exit the application "
        readline()

    rescue Exception => e
        puts e.message
    ensure
        # Clean up resources, including the container and the downloaded file
        blob_client.delete_container(container_name)
        File.delete(full_path_to_file)
    end
end

# Main method
run_sample
```

The storage name and key is getting from this place:

[image]

Comment: I'm using Bundler, so it should have been bundled.  Sorry I didn't make it clear.

I ended up putting a `require 'net/http/persistsnt'` statement in front of every function call, and it _still_ doesn't work.  The `require` statement returns `true` meaning that it is loaded, but still it comes back with this error.